# CakePHP Auth retrieve extra data

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-1.2

I am just learning CakePHP, so excuse me

I am using CakePHP 1.2.5 Auth component with UsersController. User model contains two tables:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $belongsTo = 'Company';
}
```

When login() is called, I see the data being retrieved in the SQL log (LEFT JOIN is being executed), so the model seems correct, but Auth only stores the data from `users` table and drops everything else. How can I retrieve company data later on without doing an extra query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or if you're not comfortable modifying core library like me, you could also do...

on your `UsersController.login` action

```
function login() {
    if ($this->Auth->user()) {
        $Session->write('Company', $this->User->Company->findById($this->Auth->user('id')));
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    }

}
```

You can access company details using `$this->Session->read('Company.name')` on your controller and `$session->read('Company.name')` on your views.  Don't forget to add `Session` component and helper.

Comment: It would probably be more convenient if you wrote to the `Auth.User.Company` session key. This will allow you to use the AuthComponent wrapper methods for accessing session values: `$this->Auth->user('Company.field');`

Comment: Nice approach for cases where the database is complex! For example, if you had something like `User HABTM Company (with => CompaniesUser)`. For the case scenario of OP, a simple `contain` (of course with containable behavior installed) in `$this->Auth->authenticate('Form' => array('contain' => array('Company', ...)))`. [Authentication docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html). **EDIT:** I do realize that the answer was for cake 1.2. My suggestion is for cake 2.x (that's why its a comment and not an answer!)

Answer (score 2):

in cake/libs/controller/components/auth.php on line 819, it should be

```
$data = $model->find(array_merge($find, $conditions), null, null, 0);
```

try changing it to

```
$data = $model->find(array_merge($find, $conditions), null, null, 1);
```

basically set recursive to 1
might need to do this at some other places too.

Answer (score 1):

Better than altering the core, try containable behaviour: http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable . There is a user/profile/ example near the bottom of the page.